# How to reliability pass a JSON object from API Gateway Into SQS Queue

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs, vtl, mapping-template

There does not seem to be much documentation on this, and most of the other questions don't appear to be as complete.

I would like to reliably transform a json object that hits my API Gateway endpoint into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so that I may pass it into an SQS queue.

So far I have tried every available option I could find online:

[image]

This method above produces the following body after transformation:

`MessageBody=%7B%22event_type%22%3A%22click%22%2C%22click_time%22%3A%222023-10-17T00%3A55%3A04Z%22%2C%22user_agent%22%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20(iPhone%3B%20CPU%20iPhone%20OS%2016_3_1%20like%20Mac%20OS%20X)%20AppleWebKit%2F605.1.15%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Version%2F16.3%20Mobile%2F15E148%20Safari%2F604.1%22%7D&Action=SendMessage`

I also tried:
[image]

Which produced a result similar to the one above.

In both cases, the same error was thrown within api gateway:
`Received response. Status: 404, Integration latency`

And a few lines further down:

`Endpoint response body before transformations: <UnknownOperationException/>`

I even tried to do some fancy mapping template stuff, that just didn't work (maybe you can spot the error(s) in this:

```
#set($inputJson = $input.body)

#set($urlEncodedParams = "")
#foreach($key in $inputJson.keySet())
  #set($value = $inputJson.get($key))
  #if($foreach.hasNext)
    #set($urlEncodedParams = "$urlEncodedParams${esc.url($key)}=${esc.url($value)}&")
  #else
    #set($urlEncodedParams = "$urlEncodedParams${esc.url($key)}=${esc.url($value)}")
  #end
#end

MessageBody=$urlEncodedParams&Action=SendMessage
```

**Note: I currently have no content-type headers set, it is open as that endpoint will receive both urlencoded and json data, relying on the correct mapping template to pick it up.**

Please contribute what you can, I feel like this could help many people over time if solved reliably.

Ethan

**TLDR: I want to transform JSON data hitting my api gateway into a x-www-form-encoded so I can forward it to my SQS Queue.**

Before (passed in):

```
{
  "event_type": "click",
  "click_time": "2023-10-16T22:39:59Z",
  "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
}
```

After (passed to SQS):

```
MessageBody=event_type%3Dclick%26click_time%3D2023-10-16T22%3A39%3A59Z%26user_agent%3DMozilla%2F5.0%20%28iPhone%3B%20CPU%20iPhone%20OS%2016_3_1%20like%20Mac%20OS%20X%29%20AppleWebKit%2F605.1.15%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Version%2F16.3%20Mobile%2F15E148%20Safari%2F604.1&Action=SendMessage
```

Update 2:

When I switch to a native integration like shown below, I get this error: `{"Error":{"Code":"AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue","Message":"The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version...`

[image]

Checking cloudwatch, I see:

`Sending request to https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=SendMessage`

Obviously, that's missing the path to the actual Queue, even though I include it in the request body after transformations:

```
{
    "MessageBody": "{\"event_type\":\"click\"}",
    "QueueUrl": "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/..."
}
```

Previously, I set action type to `Use Path Override` where I was able to put the Queue url directly like so:

`{ACCOUNTID}/{QUEUE-PATH}`

This worked, but not with the mapping templates below.

Comment: I don't quite get what you're after. Does your gateway receive JSON data? If your task it to "pass it into an SQS queue", why are you trying to transform it into `x-www-form-urlencoded`? Could you please post your JSON payload and the SQS message you want to get out of it?

Comment: @Quassnoi I added a tldr with an example for you!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use form? SendMessage accepts JSON requests just as easily, and it's much easier to transform JSON to JSON using VTL.

Comment: @Quassnoi was not aware of that... how would I transform JSON to JSON in VTL?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to call SQS, JSON works fine.

1. Create a native AWS Service integration:

   1. SQS for Service
   2. Path override for Action (leave the path empty)
   3. Add two headers to the integration request (the single quotes matter):

      1. `X-Amz-Target`: `'AmazonSQS.SendMessage'`
      2. `Content-Type`: `'application/x-amz-json-1.0'`
2. Use this template for `application/json`:

   ```json
   {
     "MessageBody": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))",
     "QueueUrl": "[queue-url]"
   }
   ```

This also serves as poor man's validation: if your input is not valid JSON, the endpoint will fail.

If you have proper validation in place, or if you don't care if the JSON is well-formed, you can simplify it a little bit:

```json
{
  "MessageBody": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body)",
  "QueueUrl": "[queue-url]"
}
```

Comment: what if I'm calling the queue directly from API Gateway? I thought that was the one exception where you must use urlencoded (and pass an `Action` through)

Comment: @Ethan: I don't understand how "calling the queue directly from API Gateway" is opposed to what I wrote. Did you try to implement what I wrote?

Comment: please check latest update above for additional request information

Comment: @Ethan: SQS JSON protocol is indeed slightly different. See the post update.